# How to fix 404 error XMLHttpRequest to a localhost

Tags: javascript, post, request, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

I'm receiving on the console an 404 error while I'm trying to send a post request.

I'm using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ just as a Proxy, so I can work around on my localhost and fix any cross-origin problems.

My code is:

```
function test() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    alert(this.readyState + " // " + this.status);
}
xhttp.open("POST", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost/safecom/webuser.dll/Welcome", true);
xhttp.send("flogon=test&fpwd=123456");
```

}

localhost page form is:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="Welcome">
<input type="hidden" name="redirpage" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="redirparam" id="redirparam" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="flogontext" value="User logon">
<input type="hidden" name="fpwdtext" value="PIN code">
<input type="hidden" name="flogonEnc" id="flogonEnc" value="">
<div class="login_form_element">
    <div class="login_field_user_box_border">
        <div class="login_field_user_box">
            <div class="logon_field_lbl" id="lblUserLogon" onclick="field_focus(flogon)">User logon</div>
            <input class="login_field_input" type="text" name="flogon" id="flogon" maxlength="254" size="24" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="login_form_element">
    <div class="login_field_user_box_border">
        <div class="logon_field_lbl_pwd" id="lblPassword" onclick="field_focus(fpwd)">PIN code</div>
        <input class="login_field_password_input" type="password" name="fpwd" id="fpwd" maxlength="4" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="login_form_element">
    <input id="btnloginsubmit" class="rounded_login_btn" type="submit" value="Login"></div>
```

The Chrome console points the error to the line where I send(), saying: 
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

The problem is...When I use the online version of the website it works... But I would like to point to my localhost, so I don't need to make changes on the online version.

Comment: I don't think localhost will work as that is as its name suggests only local. The heroku app doesn't know what localhost is. Try passing your public IP address.

Comment: Didn't work with public IP address

Comment: Are you hosting the page with something like Apache or nginx? If not then that's not gonna work at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`http://localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is a notation for '*my computer*'.

So when you send this URL to [`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com) for processing, the system tries to access `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/something`, because `localhost` points to its server, and that resource can't found.

Don't use the proxy or send [your](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) real [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) instead of `localhost` to fix this issue!